# Program for weighted Subgraph with vertex having same weight in Python

Tags: python, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, weighted-graph

**Question is** :
Given a weighted graph G, first find a sub-graph H of G such that all vertices of H have the same weight and the number of vertices in H is maximized. Then find a minimum spanning tree(MSP) of H such that the total edge weights is minimized. Write a program to solve this problem.  The input is a weighted graph G described by an adjacent list. Each vertex of G has an integer weight in the range of [1, floor(n/10)], where n is the number of vertices in G. Each edge has an integer weight in the range of [1,10n].

---

*I have tried many ways to solve the problem but no progress. I assume graph to be undirected and complete graph. Can anyone help me with the solution?*

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried of grouping the vertices of the graph according to the weights and then finding the subgraph with maximum number of vertices. But grouping goes complex as I tried sorting the vertices according to weights.